# Different row separator for multiple rows in tikz dependency

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want row space for the four rows differently in the below mentioned example. For example 1ex for first 2 rows, 4ex for 2 and 3 rows and 1ex for last 2 rows. Setting row sep gives equal spacing for all the four rows. How can I vary the space between each row pair separately. I also want alignments shown by lines between words in the 2nd and 3rd row.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=.5cm]
%\begin{deptext}[column sep=.5cm]
PRP\$ \& NN \& RB \&[.5cm] VBZ \& VBG \& NN \\ 
My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \& sausage \\ \\[2ex]
mere\& kuta \& bhi \& sausage \& khana \& pasand \\
PRP\$ \& NN \& RB \&[.5cm] VBZ \& VBG \& NN \\
\end{deptext}
\deproot{4}{root}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\draw [-,out=90,in=-90,thick, red] (\wordref{2}{6})--    (\wordref{3}{4});     %\wordref{row}{col} 
\draw [-,out=90,in=-90,thick, red] (\wordref{2}{4})--(\wordref{3}{6}); %\wordref{row}{col} 
\end{dependency}%}
\end{deptext}
\end{document}
```

I will really appreciate your help. I could not find anything related in the tikz-dependency manual.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: This said, it may be enough to replace the line endings `\\ ` with something like `\\[1ex]`, `\\1[ex]`, `\\[4ex]`, ... I'd check if you'd given a MWE:)

Comment: All set! Row changes with the separator. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from user30471 works. I had a similar issue and tested it out and adding:

`\\[4ex]`

to the end of the row and it solved the problem.

If the issue is with 1 row merging into the row **above**, you need to add row-spacing to the top row because the spacing goes downwards.

The spacing works through normal logic:

`\\[4ex]` is greater than `\\[1ex]` and so forth.